# Caracteres especiales en escritura a ficheros Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy realizando un script en python para organizar y contar palabras de un texto dado por un fichero. El problema lo tengo al imprimirlo a otro fichero.

El código que imprime al fichero es este:

```
def printToFile(self, fileName):
    file_to_print = open(fileName, 'w')
    file_to_print.write(str(self))
    file_to_print.close()
```

y aquí el str de la clase llamado en mi otro método:

```
def __str__(self):
    cadena = ""
    for key in self.processedWords:
        cadena += str(key) + ": " + str(self.processedWords[key]) + "\n"
    return cadena.decode('string_escape')
```

La cuestión es que si lo imprimo por la consola no hay errores, el problema llega al imprimirlo en el fichero que aparecen de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta debería de ser la salida del fichero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas poner las cabeceras al principio de cada archivo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Y luego ya puedes utilizar la codificación utf-8 en los strings:

```
def printToFile(self, fileName):
    file_to_print = open(fileName, 'w','utf-8')
    file_to_print.write(str.encode('utf8')(self))
    file_to_print.close()
```

Comment: Me salta un error diciendo que "encoding='utf-8'" no es un argumento válido para .open()

Comment: Que versión de python estas utilizando?

Comment: Para python 3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Prueba sin el encoding, como he editado el ejemplo.

Comment: estoy usando python 3, si, y ya está solucionado, gracias!